# error trying to write multiple jpegs to file in r

Tags: r, loops, file, jpeg, r-s4

I have over 600 WAV files I am trying to plot and write to a file. I made a loop to do this, but it gives an error that says
"Error in audiomoth13_allfiles@left : trying to get slot "left" from an object of a basic class
("list") with no slots"

Below is my code that produces the error.

```
for (audiomoth13wavfiles in seq_along(audiomoth13_allfiles)) {
audiomoth13_allfiles<-lapply(audiomoth13wavfiles,readWave)
snd<-audiomoth13_allfiles@left 
fs<-audiomoth13_allfiles@samp.rate
dur<-length(snd)/audiomoth13_allfiles@samp.rate
snd<-snd-mean(snd)
timearray<-(0:(5760000-1))/audiomoth13_allfiles@samp.rate
jpeg(file= paste0("C:/ACLF_Audiomoth_13/ACLF_Audiomoth_13/plots",names(audiomoth13wavfiles) 
[audiomoth13wavfiles],".jpeg"))
plot(timearray,snd,type='l',xlab='Time',ylab='Amplitude')
dev.off()}
```

The error occurs whether or not I put audiomoth13_allfiles<-lapply(audiomoth13wavfiles,readWave)
in the loop. audiomoth13_allfiles contains all the files as an S4 object with slots

Is there another way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating a `for` loop with `lapply`, which is sort of redundant. Try something akin to what is shown below (or use a `for` loop instead of `lapply`).
The idea is to loop through the indices of all .wav files. This way you can use the same index for the file name and the file read in using `readWave`.

```r
library(tuneR)
wavfiles <- list.files(pattern="*.wav")
lapply(seq_along(wavfiles), function(x){
    wav <- readWave(wavfiles[x])
    snd <- wav@left
    fs <- wav@samp.rate
    dur <- length(snd)/fs
    snd <- snd - mean(snd)
    timearray <- seq(0, dur, length.out=length(snd))
    jpeg(file=paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(wavfiles[x]), "_plot.jpg"))
        plot(snd~timearray, type='l', xlab='Time', ylab='Amplitude')
    dev.off()}
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gave the same error Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  trying to get slot "left" from an object of a basic class ("character") with no slots

Comment: You have to adjust the code or set your working directory to the directory containing the wav files. In the case above, the wav files are in the working directory. Your error suggests there were no files to process. You could adjust e.g. `wavfiles <-  list.files(pattern="*.wav", path = "/path/to/my/wavfiles", full.names = TRUE)` with the actual path to your wav files.